# How to pentest oAuth2/oidc clients

Tags: penetration-test, oauth2, openid-connect

imagine the following problem:

As a developer, I would like to check if my oAuth2 or OpenID Connect client is really secure.
I would like to check if it validates the JWT signature, uses the nonce etc.

While I can do these tests all manually, I am sure that there is also an automated way, but I can't find it via google or other means.

Is there such a tool already available?

Answer (score 3):

There is a JWT attack playbook.
A simple yet effective attack methodology is developed and automated by "ticarpi" :

**The Setup:**

- Find JWT tokens
- Identify a test page
- Check that your test cases work (replay the token)

**The simple checks**

- Is it required?
- Is it checked?
- Is it persistent? (Does it continue working after failed tokens are
  sent)
- Where is it created?
- Are the claims processed before/despite validation?
- Weak HMAC secret used as a key

**The basic exploits**

- 'none' Algorithm (CVE-2015-9235)
- RSA Key Confusion (CVE-2016-5431)
- JWKS Injection (CVE-2018-0114)
- null signature (CVE-2020-28042)

**The advanced tests**

- "kid" issues - reveal key
- "kid" issues - path traversal
- URL Tampering Attacks
- JWKS Spoofing

**Extra checks**

- Cross-service relay attacks
- Does the expiry get checked?

These checks and more could be conducted by [jwt_tool](https://github.com/ticarpi/jwt_tool)

Ex:

```
python3 jwt_tool.py -t https://api.test.com/v1/apps -rh "Authorization: Bearer token"  -M pb
```

Comment: thanx for this answer, I fear that those modified tokes will be rejected because of a wrong or missing signature. How will I approach this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your concern! It's a good news if the modified token is rejected isn't it?

Comment: if the token is already rejected because of a wrong signature, there is no way to test for the other issues like expiry check.

Comment: Ah, no the tool keep the "original" token and make a change/test a time, so you don't need to handle this, the script do it.
I Edited the response to include a "working" command

Comment: There also is the OIDC certification test on https://openID.net/certification/ … especially handy if you want to validate more the total implementation that just the tokens.

Comment: the certification is interesting. As I do understand, it certifies the providers and not the clients, correct? I am looking for something automated for the cient side...